# Checking that an order has a product with a specific attribute value Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, taxonomy-terms

I'm to go check if a product added to cart and purchased is in an order. I.e when a user purchase a variable product along with other variable products, i want to check if a specific variable product is added and purchased. So that i can dynamically show some information on the Thankyou Page and email sent to both the admin and customer.

I have tried to use *"[Checking that a specific attribute value is used in a cart Item (product variation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41304266/checking-that-a-specific-attribute-value-is-used-in-a-cart-item-product-variati/41306277#41306277)"* answer code, **but this doesn't work on Thankyou page once the product is purchased**.

What I am trying is to display a dynamic content if products in the order has an attribute value of "Custom", as well as display an additional table row to the order table if there is a product in the order having the attribute value "order", with the following code:

```
function add_custom_row_to_order_table( $total_rows, $myorder_obj  ) {
     if ( is_attr_in_cart('custom') ) {
            $cmeasuement = __( 'Yes', 'domain' );
      }else{
            $cmeasuement = __( 'No', 'domain' );
     }

    $total_rows['el_custom'] = array(
       'label' => __('Custom Required?', 'domain'),
       'value'   => $cmeasuement,
    );

    return $total_rows;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'add_custom_row_to_order_table', 10, 2 );
```

But I keep Getting "No" *(see the screenshot below)* and the reason is because the `is_attr_in_cart('custom')` function is not detecting if the attribute is in the order. Help in the right direction to getting it to detect if an order has a product with specific attribute value.

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it work with WooCommerce **orders** you need another custom conditional function *(where `$attribute_value` is the **slug** value of a product attribute that you are targeting)*:

```
function is_attr_in_order( $order, $attribute_value ){
    $found = false; // Initializing

    // Loop though order items
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ){
        // Only for product variations
        if( $item->get_variation_id() > 0 ){
            $product = $item->get_product(); // The WC_Product Object
            $product_id = $item->get_product_id(); // Product ID

            // Loop through product attributes set in the variation
            foreach( $product->get_attributes() as $taxonomy => $term_slug ){
                // comparing attribute parameter value with current attribute value
                if ( $attribute_value === $term_slug ) {
                    $found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if($found) break;
    }

    return $found;
}
```

Now this conditional function will work in your code on order received page *(thankyou)*, adding an additional row to total table with "Yes" if the product attribute is found or "No" if not:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'add_custom_row_to_order_table', 10, 3 );
function add_custom_row_to_order_table( $total_rows, $order, $tax_display  ) {
    $domain    = 'woocommerce'; // The text domain (for translations)
    $term_slug = 'custom'; // <==  The targeted product attribute slug value

    $total_rows['custom'] = array(
       'label' => __( "Custom Required?", $domain ),
       'value'   => is_attr_in_order( $order, $term_slug ) ? __( "Yes", $domain ) : __( "No", $domain ),
    );

    return $total_rows;
}
```

*Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme)*. Tested and works.

---

If you need to only target Order received page you will use inside your hooked function this condition:

```
if( is_wc_endpoint_url('order-received') ) {
    // The code comes here
}
return $total_rows; // The final filter return outside
```

Comment: You're a life saver ... Thanks @LoicTheAztec